# Keyboard and mouse stop working at login/recovery mode of new 14.04 install

Tags: 14.04, grub2, keyboard, xorg, mouse

This morning I tried to install amd drivers on my 14.04 lts ubuntu. It rebooted to a blank screen and nothing I was doing in recovery mode fixed it.
(Uninstalling fglrx-* etc) Then I unwisely followed a tutorial which told me to uninstall and reinstall xserver-xorg, it wouldn't reinstall without errors so in desperation I burnt a new live cd and used the upgrade option in the install to reinstall to 14.04 hoping to avoid data loss.

Now I get to the login screen and my keyboard and mouse stop working. They work before this in bios and the grub menu, but not in recovery mode either.

Other people have had similar problems but recovery mode is working for them so they can resolve it from there but there's nothing out of my mouse/keyboard after grub menu.

Comment: 15.10 is not supported. I suggest installing 14.04 or 16.04 from scratch.

Comment: Ok, is there a way to do this keeping my old home directory, My last backup was about 2 weeks ago and I'd prefer not to loose the data.

Comment: Yes, you can keep it is you use manual partitioning and keep your `/home` partition, or do not format `/` if there is no a separate `/home`.

Comment: Ok I reinstalled 14.04 without reformatting / and I'm having the same issue. If my /home is separate can I reformat / because I think the error is there?

Comment: You can create a new user and test. If under a new user the problem disappears, then it is  there.

Comment: If you have the same issue with 14.04 please [edit] the question and remove references to 15.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase anyone is having the same issue, this is how I fixed it. (Note. These instructions work where the /, and /home were originally placed on separate partitions)

1.) Reinstall 14.04 from live CD and choose "something else" as type of install

2.) Without changing the size, set your / partition by formatting, selecting as Ext 4 and putting / as mount point.

3.) Do NOT format the partiton where /home is. Just select as Ext 4 and put /home as mount point, do NOT change the size. (This is important as if you format it you will loose all your files which you're trying to preserve)

4.) Use the same username and password as before to get back to your files.